Symfony and API Plattform Login Authentication "401 JWT Token missing"
I have a symfony app (currently with twig FE and login form auth). On the same app I would like to add an API to share
the same resources to other platforms. I added the API platform package to easy build an API.
According to the docs it should be possible to run both "sides" API and plain old PHP controllers (twig FE) at the same
time, but I tried out several options (from other questions here) but got only one side working.
Do I need a separate extra login/ firewall? How to implement so that its possible to read the API docs after login and
have the API resources stateless with jwt authentication?
What I would like to have is:

/* all pointing to the controllers
/api/v1 pointing to the swagger docs
/api/v1/{resource} pointing to an API resource (json+ld, stateless)

Symfony Version 6.4 (updated from 6.2)
Here's the repo: https://github.com/michitheonlyone/symfony-webapp-plattform-base/tree/DEV-RBAC
Here is my config/security.yaml
security:
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
  enable_authenticator_manager: true
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    api:
      pattern: ^/api/v1/
      stateless: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      jwt: ~
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: app_logout
      json_login:
        check_path: auth # The name in routes.yaml is enough for mapping
        username_path: email
        password_path: password
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
    - { path: ^/api/v1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI docs
    - { path: ^/auth, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

and my config/routes.yaml
controllers:
  resource:
    path: ../src/Controller/
    namespace: App\Controller
  type: attribute

auth:
  path: /auth
  methods: [ 'POST' ]

My config/api_plattform.yaml
api_platform:
  title: Symfony BaseApp
  version: 1.0.0
  # Good defaults for REST APIs
  defaults:
    stateless: true
    cache_headers:
      vary: [ 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin' ]
    extra_properties:
      standard_put: true

  show_webby: false

  swagger:
    api_keys:
      JWT:
        name: Authorization
        type: header

my config/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
  public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
  pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'

  api_platform:
    check_path: /auth
    username_path: email
    password_path: password

Building an App with symfony with an extra API. The regular login form works fine.
Error Message "401 JWT Token not found". on the API Docs.

What I tried is to switch the firewall so that api comes after the main. this worked until I made a request to an API
resource I got the message:


"500 - Session was used while the request was declared stateless"
2. when I do it stateless it works but that's not the goal due to security the API should be stateless!

